# Firebase Crashlytics stuck adding SDK

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I'm trying to add the Crashlytics SDK to my Android app, but it seems to be having trouble communicating with the Firebase servers. I've followed all of the instructions per the docs, but the Crashlytics tab in my console has been stuck on this screen for about 6 or so hours:
[crashlytics add sdk screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NegRP.jpg).

I would (ideally) get this to just work™️, but if not then I'd like to be able to restart the process, but I also don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi @ethan, Please provide more informations like plateforme Android/iOS, language, SDK version.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out - I was mistakenly using the same appplicationID as another one of my projects, so Firebase was getting confused - making an entirely new project with a different applicationID fixed my problem.

Comment: This was my issue and my solution, but why?! I added a Firebase project to existing older Google Cloud project. I can't change the App ID. Does anyone have an opinion?

Answer (score 0):

if you followed all the steps as latest documentation..crash the app( use fatalError() for crash) using button action, this trick works for me.

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios&authuser=0#force-test-crash

For me Create a crash on button in project Relaunch application by simulator not by Xcode and It worked for me.